# libprotoc compiling protoc files but not other protoc included in it (google grpc assistant annotations.pb.h no file or directory error)

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, protocol-buffers, google-assistant-sdk, protoc

I am trying to generate Google Assistant library in C++.
I have compiled the *embedded_assistant.proto* file using protoc compiler and obtained the *embedded_assistant.grpc.pb.h* and *embedded_assistant.grpc.pb.cc* files for library.
I created a client file *ea_main.cc* and included these files in it.

When i try to compile *ea_main.cc* using g++ compiler I get this error.

```
car@ubuntu:~/grpc/examples/cpp/embedded_assistant$ g++ -I./ ea_main.cc -o OUT_CPP_TEST -std=c++11
In file included from embedded_assistant.grpc.pb.h:22:0,           
                 from ea_main.cc:9:
embedded_assistant.pb.h:33:39: fatal error: google/api/annotations.pb.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

In the *embedded_assistant.proto* file there is another proto file included in it as

```
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "google/rpc/status.proto";
```

It seems that the protoc didnt compiled or generated headers for these .proto files. When looked in *google/api/* they ere not there.

So thats why the g++ compiler is giving errors for the missing annotations.pb.h file.

Why the protoc didnt compiled the proto included in *embedded_assistant.proto*
?How can I get these files??
Is something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution i.e. include other required protos while compiling like:-

```
protoc --proto_path=protos --cpp_out=. protos/embedded_assistant.proto protos/google/api/annotations.proto protos/google/api/http.proto protos/google/rpc/status.proto
```